# How to stop player accelerating when it shouldn't be

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

In the main game loop, a movement key press changes the player state:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_w:
            player.state = "moving_up"
    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_w:
            player.state = "stopping_up"
```

When the player update method is called, it moves according to the state:

```
def update(self):
    if self.state == "idle":
        self.displacement = self.displacement
    else:            
        if self.state == "moving_up":
            self.displacement[1] = self.displacement[1] - self.speed
        if self.state == "stopping_up":
            s = self.rect.top % 32
            self.displacement[1] = self.displacement[1] - s
            self.state = "idle"
        new_position = self.rect.move(self.displacement)
        self.rect = new_position
```

When I move the player, the speed seems to be accelerating after each consequent press of the key. e.g. the first time i move the speed is fine, but the next time it is even faster than before and it just snowballs...

Here is a print out of the (speed), (displacement) when moving right:

```
idle
0.02 [0.7200000000000003, 0]
0.02 [0.7400000000000003, 0]
0.02 [0.7600000000000003, 0]

...

0.02 [1.2400000000000007, 0]
0.02 [1.2600000000000007, 0]
0.02 [19.26, 0]
idle
```

You can see that on the last movement the displacement increases greatly.

Any idea why this is happening?

---

update, here is another print out with s:

```
0.02 [1.1600000000000006, 0]
0.02 [1.1800000000000006, 0]
0.02 [1.2000000000000006, 0]
0.02 [1.2200000000000006, 0]
0.02 [1.2400000000000007, 0]
0.02 [1.2600000000000007, 0]
s: remainder to next tile 18
0.02 [19.2600000000000007, 0]
```

It looks like s is causing the jump in displacement.

This was intentional as it was supposed to find the distance to the next tile and make the player move there. (tiles are 32x32) and s was the remainder until the next one.

Seems like I need to revise the movement code as it's not resulting in what I expected.

Comment: The obvious thing here is that the final value is using `s` rather than `self.speed`.  Print `s` out too (ie, it's using the `"stopping_up"` condition).  If it's not that, we don't have enough information to solve this.

Comment: Agreed, need to see the values of `s`. Also, why are you using `%` (the modulo operator) when calculating `s`? It would make sense that the value jumps, since `s` will jump after `self.rect.top` passes a multiple of 32

Comment: @tom10 i have updated the post, looks like s was the culprit.

Comment: OK, I guess I'll write this as an answer just to give the problem some closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious thing here is that the final value is using `s` rather than `self.speed`.

As a side note:
 In general, in doing physical simulations, it's best to use physical units.  By this I mean, think of time in seconds, not loop passes, etc, and work from this.  If you want to increment a distance using a speed, do this as `dist += dt*speed`, not `dist += speed`.  Usually this involves and extra multiplication, but it's well worth it.  Otherwise, you're effectively using time units so that `dt=1.`, which is possible, but trickier than it seems at first.

Here, for example, you're adding `self.displacement[1] - self.speed`, and in the next line you do `self.displacement[1] = self.displacement[1] - s`, where `s` seems to be a distance.  Although in numbers these two things look similar, physically they are very different.  It's not surprising there was a bug here because the whole thing is hard to understand.

Comment: I'm updating the physics every dt and it was hard to figure out the correct speed to travel the width of a tile every dt. Say my timestep is 0.01, and i want the player to move 32 px (one tile) in 0.20 seconds. That's 160 px/s. Every time i call the update function the player's displacement (s) = 800.0 * dt?

Comment: One advantage of using time in your calculations is you can write standard equations.  V=D/T or D=V*T.  You say you want V = 32p/(0.20sec)=160p/sec.  So then dD = V*dT = (160p/sec)*(0.01sec) = 1.6p: if you want to move further, you need a different velocity or more time.  Note when you call this 20x (0.2/.01) you move the desired 32p.  I guess you're getting 800 from (160p/sec)/(0.2sec), but note the units for this is 800p/(sec^2), which is not a distance (and having real units to do this type of check is another advantage of using a real time).